# Way to view/parse JSON without giving data to a third party?

Tags: json, formatting

Say I have a string of JSON formatted data that is private.  As a hypothetical example we can say that it includes the names, phone numbers, social security numbers and credit card numbers for my top 10 customers (not really).

I need to view this data in a readable format.  There are many many websites out there that can help me.  But I have to give them the data (bad).

**Is there a way to get JSON data formatted like what the various websites do without having to give my data to a website?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can download **JSON Viewer** from CodePlex.

http://jsonviewer.codeplex.com/

It is an EXE file.

Or, you can use a Json Viewer Plugin for **Notepad++**

http://sourceforge.net/projects/nppjsonviewer/

Answer (score 1):

I am a fan of node's [jsontool](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jsontool).  On the commandline, just stream your text in and it will give you pretty-printed validated json out.

```
npm install -g jsontool
json < my.json
```

There are many plugins for popular browsers too, like [JSONView](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc/related?hl=en), but that may not meet your security requirements.

Answer (score 0):

[JSONView for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc) 
can be used to view **local** JSON files from your disk drive.